# css background image only working in chrome and safari?

Tags: css, background

hey guys,
i cannot find an answer.

```
body {
    background: #fff url('images/years.png') no-repeat top 85%;
}
```

why is this background image working in chrome and safari but not in firefox and ie?
any idea what could cause that behaviour?

It seems like background-position is causing the bug! top 85% work in chrome and safari, but do not in IE and firefox!

Comment: Can you show an example? What does Firebug say about the body element?

Comment: Can you post an example to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: the problem is there is no firebug for firefox 4! IE8 Developertools doesn't show a background-image declared in my css.

Comment: no, no chaching problem, just doesn't work. i'll try to download firefox 3.6 again

Comment: If it's not a caching problem, you're probably doing something a bit silly. Sorry! I think you should edit your question to include ALL relevant code.

Comment: Hmm, even if the path was incorrect, IE8 dev tools would still show it as declared - does it show the other rules on that element? Is this rule on the page in question, or in an external style sheet? Has the style sheet been loaded correctly in IE and FF?

Comment: @mathiregister Firebug does exist for Fx4. Just check FB 1.7 alpha on http://getfirebug.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your background-position isn't logical.
You should write `85% top` (X then Y).
I know 'top' can't define a X position and Chrome/Safari probably figure this out, but Firefox/IE don't understand it.

Comment: Curious, testing in IE8 using the CSS provided seemed to work ok, assuming the image paths were correct.

Comment: Btw, you could write `85% 0` which is shorter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they don't like the compact syntax. Use:

```
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url('images/years.png');
background-position: top 85%;
```

Comment: That's soooooooooooooooo not the reason :)

Comment: Well, of course it works: both your syntax and the syntax in the question is valid CSS.

Comment: Except that it doesn't apply `no-repeat`

Comment: it does show up now when i don't use the compact syntax. However it seems the background-position is causing the bug somehow. check my edits!